# So I wrote this code but the loop doesn't work

Tags: c

So I was given this problem, where I am to calculate and decide if a number(between 1 and 100) is special or not. If the sum of the digits is multiplied by 4 and the result is equal to the original number, then that number is a special number. So I wrote the code. But the loop is not working. Outside of any loop the code works without any issue where variable number may have any value. What might be the issue? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number;
    int originalnumber;

for(number=1;number<=100;number++)
{           
    originalnumber = number;

    int sum = 0, result;

    while(number>0)
    {
        result = number % 10;
        sum = sum + result;
        number = number / 10;
    }

    if((sum*4)==originalnumber)
    {
        printf("\n%d is special number.", originalnumber);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%d is not special number.", originalnumber);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If any answer answered your question, please consider accepting it (greed checkmark to the left of the answer). This will give some reputation to you and the answerer and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're modifying the variable that iterates the loop: `number`.

As you did with `originalnumber`, also make a copy of `number` so you can modify it, without messing with the loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you are modifying the "number" variable that is used in the for loop.
You could just swap the originalnumber in the loop as shown below and assign number the sequence:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number;
    int originalnumber;

    for(originalnumber=1;originalnumber<=100;originalnumber++)
    {           
        number = originalnumber;

        int sum = 0, result;

        while(number>0)
        {
            result = number % 10;
            sum = sum + result;
            number = number / 10;
        }

        if((sum*4)==originalnumber)
        {
            printf("\n%d is special number.", originalnumber);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n%d is not special number.", originalnumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use 'number' variable in while loop. Modification of the variable that iterate the outer loop causing the abnormal behavior here.

Answer (score 0):

See you are changing value of number in the while loop and every time it is becoming zero. so assign number value to a new variable and then do changes on that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int number;
int originalnumber;

for(number=1;number<=100;number++)
{           
originalnumber = number;

int sum = 0, result;

while(originalnumber >0)
{
    result = originalnumber % 10;
    sum = sum + result;
    originalnumber = originalnumber / 10;
}

if((sum*4)==number)
{
    printf("\n%d is special number.", number);
}
else
{
    printf("\n%d is not special number.", number);
}
```

}
}